# How to prove that Sum of two open sets is open?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two subsets of $\Bbb R$. Define $X + Y = \{x + y : x \in X, y \in Y\}$
How to prove that $X + Y$ is open ?

I see somewhere that $X + Y$ is open if either $X$ or $Y$ or both $X$ and $Y$ are open.

(1)
I know that $X$ is open if $X^c$ is closed. Where $X^c$ denotes the complement of $X$

(2)
$X$ is called open if it is neighborhood of each of its points.

(3)
$X \cup Y$ and $X \cap Y$ are open if $X$ and $Y$ are open.

Comment: Check out the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80970/is-there-a-pair-of-open-sets-whose-minkowski-sum-is-not-open).

Comment: I could not understand it from here.

Comment: Say $X$ is open. Then $X+Y=\bigcup_{y\in Y}(X+y)$ is a union of open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open if each of its points is contained in an open interval that lies in the subset.

Let $x+y \in X + Y$. By openness of $Y$, there is an open interval $I_y$ with $y \in I_y \subset Y$. Now, $x + I_y \subset X + Y$ is also an open interval that contains $x+y$.

Note that we have only used openness of one of the sets.

Comment: How $x + I_y$ is open ?

Comment: $I_y$ is of the form $(a,b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, $x+I_y = (x+a, x+b)$ which is also an open interval.

Comment: It means $X + Y$ is open when $Y$ is open and $X$ is either open or closed.

Comment: The sum of two sets (in $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology) is open if one of them is open. No assumption on the other set is needed.